# If your server runs out of space does your DB reject insert queries (or all queries)

Tags: mysql

If your server runs out of disk space does that automatically mean that your database will now reject any queries or does Mysql reserve space on the disk for growth?

Comment: There will generally be some [pre-allocated space](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-space.html), but your monitoring should catch such things loooooong before it's a concern. You're focusing on the wrong question - "how do I make sure I *don't* run out of space?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server runs out of space you're deep into the danger zone:

- Queries that insert may fail.
- Queries that require temporary tables may fail.
- Queries that require transactions may fail.
- Everything is going to be on fire.

This is why you **must have alerting on your server** for when you're close to exhausting your disk space. Temporary tables can get quite large, temporary files may be created by the operating system, so operating at 98% full *will* be risky.